# How to get a facebook page with URL like facebook.com/mycompany

Tags: facebook

I've seen other facebook 'company/brand/product' pages with URLs of the format: facebook.com/mycompany

How do you set this up?

If I use pages/create, I get an address like: facebook.com/pages/mycompany/234266

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you receive 25 "Likes" on your page, you will see the option to create a permalink.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the page and then click on Basic Information on the left and then you can specify the URL under Username.